# How to create a new variable and assign it a value corresponding to another variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

Here is some mock data corresponding to the real dataset I am using:

## mock dataset

```
    a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
    b <- 1:10
    names <-c("Alex","Ale","Alexandra","Alexander","Ali","Amanda","Alix","Ajax","Aley","Ajay")
    data <- data.frame(a,b,names)
```

## create new variable gender

```
    data <- data %>% 
      mutate(gender = NA)
```

I want to assign a "gender" value to the `names` variable in my dataset. I don't want to do this manually because I am dealing with 1000s of observations. I do however have these variables, which contain the "names" value corresponding to the right gender:

```
male <- c("Alex", "Ale", "Alexander")
female <- c("Alexandra", "Ali", "Amanda")
noanswer <- c("Alix", "Ajax", "Aley", "Ajay")
```

However I don't know how to use them to assign a "gender" value to correspond with specific "names" in my dataset.

Here is what I tried:

```
data$gender[data$names== male] <- "Male"
```

And:

```
data$gender[data$names== c("Alex", "Ale", "Alexander")] <- "Male"
```

This code does not assign "Male" to all of the values. I recieve a warning message:

```
"Warning message:
In data$names == c("Alex", "Ale", "Alexander") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

Does anyone know how I can assign values to my `gender` variable corresponding to the `names` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a named `list` and then `stack` it to a two column dataset, which we use in a join

```
new <- stack(list(male = male, female = female, noanswer = noanswer))
names(new) <- c("names", "gender")
data <- data %>% 
    left_join(new, by = "names")
```

-output

```
data
   a  b     names   gender
1  a  1      Alex     male
2  b  2       Ale     male
3  c  3 Alexandra   female
4  d  4 Alexander     male
5  e  5       Ali   female
6  f  6    Amanda   female
7  g  7      Alix noanswer
8  h  8      Ajax noanswer
9  i  9      Aley noanswer
10 j 10      Ajay noanswer
```

---

Regarding the OP's `warning`, it is just that `==` is elementwise comparison and that is applicable mostly when the `length` of 1 of the datasets is either 1 (which gets recycled) or be the same `length` as the other one.  Here, the `length`s are different.  So, it gets recycled and as it is not a multiple of the other vector length, there is warning.  But, sometimes we don't get warning, but still it is incorrect because what it does is similar to the one below.  If the second vector is of length 3 and first is 5

```
v1[1] == v2[1]
v1[2] == v2[2]
v1[3] == v2[3]
v1[4] == v2[1]
...
```

Instead, we may use `%in%`

```
data$gender[data$names %in% male] <- "Male"
data$gender[data$names %in% female] <- "Female"
data$gender[data$names %in% noanswer] <- "noanswer"
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j"), b = 1:10, names = c("Alex", "Ale", "Alexandra", "Alexander", 
"Ali", "Amanda", "Alix", "Ajax", "Aley", "Ajay")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

male <- c("Alex", "Ale", "Alexander")
female <- c("Alexandra", "Ali", "Amanda")
noanswer <- c("Alix", "Ajax", "Aley", "Ajay")

data %>%
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    names %in% male ~ "Male",
    names %in% female ~ "Female",
    names %in% noanswer ~ "Noanswer"
  ))

   a  b     names   gender
1  a  1      Alex     Male
2  b  2       Ale     Male
3  c  3 Alexandra   Female
4  d  4 Alexander     Male
5  e  5       Ali   Female
6  f  6    Amanda   Female
7  g  7      Alix Noanswer
8  h  8      Ajax Noanswer
9  i  9      Aley Noanswer
10 j 10      Ajay Noanswer
```